# How do I make a thread print a list whenever it is updated?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make it so that the function `foo()` can continually wait until the array `array` has been changed so it can print it out.

I'm coming from C so there's a possibility I'm overcomplicating this. This is what I tried.

I have two condition variables, `cv1` tells `foo` whether a change to an array has been made, and `cv2` notifies when `foo()` is finished printing `array`.

Right now nothing happens. I think it's getting stuck in a loop. If anyone knows a simpler solution to this it would be appreciated.

```
import threading
import time
import logging

array = None
updated = False
terminate = False
finishedPrinting = False

def foo():
  with cv1:
    while True:
      while not updated and not terminate:
        cv1.wait()
      if terminate:
        return

      print array
      updated = False
      with cv2:
        logging.debug('Finished printing array')
        finishedPrinting = True
        cv2.notify()

cv1 = threading.Condition()
cv2 = threading.Condition()

with cv1:
  array = [1, 2, 3]
  updated = True
  cv1.notify()

with cv2:
  while not finishedPrinting:
    cv2.wait()
  finishedPrinting = False

with cv1:
  array = [5, 2, 1, 1]
  updated = True
  cv1.notify()

with cv2:
  while not finishedPrinting:
    cv2.wait()
  finishedPrinting = False

with cv1:
    terminate = True
    cv1.notify()

t1 = threading.Thread(name='thread', target=foo, args=(cv1, cv2))
t1.start()
```

Comment: Seems like a single condition-variable and a mutex would be simpler (or if you're always going to have one thread wait while the other thread performs an action, then you could just not have a second thread and get the same behavior using a simple function call within a single thread)

Comment: With your current code formatting 1/2 of `foo()` is unreachable.  How do you escape from `while not finishedPrinting` followed by `cv2.wait()`? This is where you hang forever.

Comment: @JonSG I fixed that and I get the same problem.

Comment: if `not updated and not terminate` it's waiting in `while True` , if `terminate` it returns. `foo()` will never reach after `if terminate`

Comment: @doubleE `terminate` is just to know when the program ends. This code is translated from C and in my C program everything works perfectly (see my previous post's answer for the code). I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent code in Python would be.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I want `foo()` to always be 'on' in the background waiting for a signal that the array has been modified, so it can print it. Doesn't that require a seperate thread?

Comment: @templateboy multiple threads are necessary in order to get your program to execute two (or more) streams of execution asynchronously (with respect to each other).  But if you're going to always (conceptually-speaking) "pause" thread A while thread B runs, and then when B is completed, have B go back to sleep and have A resume again... well, that's effectively no different from the behavior of a function-call in a single-threaded program, so you could implement that behavior much more easily and efficiently by not spawning the second thread in the first place.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The thing is I'm not allowed to leave (or return) from the foo() method to get a new array. I need to have foo() continuously wait for a new array to be made so it can print it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had the creation of the thread at the bottom of the file when it should be at the beginning:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(name='thread', target=compress, args=(cv1, cv2))
t1.start()
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

with cv1:
  array = ['z','b','y','e','y','f','w','q','q']
  updated = True
  cv1.notify()
logging.debug('Updated')

with cv2:
  while not finishedProcessing:
    cv2.wait()
  finishedProcessing = False
logging.debug('Finished printing array')


with cv1:
  array = ['o','c','b','a','a','s']
  updated = True
  cv1.notify()
logging.debug('Updated')

with cv2:
  while not finishedProcessing:
    cv2.wait()
  finishedProcessing = False
logging.debug('Finished printing array')

with cv1:
    terminate = True
    cv1.notify()
```